# iphone xcode 4 CSSMERR_TP_CERT_NOT_VALID_YET

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've set up a provisioning profile in the keychain etc but I keep getting this error when trying to create an IPA

CSSMERR_TP_CERT_NOT_VALID_YET
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

I read somewhere that "clean all contacts" might help, does anybody know where this option is?

EDIT: I just noticed in the keychain the certificate says "This certificate is not yet valid" how do I fix this?

Comment: how did you create the ipa... did you follow the exact steps?

Comment: Found the answer, the system clock was set incorrectly - hence not YET valid. It must  check local time against the certificate issue time. [i can't answer my own question due to account restriction]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few steps you can follow to see whether the issue works out. (Note: I know some of these are basic steps, but I'm listing them down since they're some of the steps I myself would follow given the same situation)

- Is your system clock running the correct time?
- You might be having an outdated version of the cert. Try downloading the cert again from the portal and reinstalling it.
- If XCode still complains, under BUILD menu select 'Clean All Targets' and the Build your project again
- Under WINDOW menu, select Organizer. Go to Provisioning section and see whether you have the necessary profiles installed. And see if everything looks 'green' i.e. no red / errors
- Do a 'Get Info' on BOTH your Project and your Target and ensure that the proper Certificate is set to the proper Profile

Comment: You're welcome jimsmith, and I appreciate you marking my post as answered, though you seem to have found the solution at the same time :) Cheers!

Comment: System clock for me too after system crash. Thanks for saving me some trouble!

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar problem and it wasn't that my system clock was set wrong, but the certificate had been "created" a few hours in the future, probably on a system in a different time zone. I changed my system clock to a few hours in the future to fake it out and VIOLA!